# Strange "RuntimeError: ERROR 160195: An invalid SQL statement was used". when trying to debug SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, sql, cursor

I'm trying to get a SearchCursor to function in my script. According to everything I could find, this should have worked. The code reads like this:

```
with arcpy.SearchCursor(sickTrees,'OID@') as cursor:
    for numb in distList:
        print('hi')
```

Edit: This is the full code now

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
sickTrees=r"C:\Users\Owen Hansen\Desktop\Python GIS\Ch5\Chapter5_LabData\Chapter5_assignmentData.gdb\sicktrees"#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fineTrees=r"C:\Users\Owen Hansen\Desktop\Python GIS\Ch5\Chapter5_LabData\Chapter5_assignmentData.gdb\healthytrees"#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
distList=[5,10,15,20,25]
test='OID@'
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sickTrees,test) as cursor:#It is on fine, help, this bloody SQL error won't go away
for numb in distList:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sickTrees,test) as cursor:#fixed it by moving the cursor creation
        count=0#should reset, isn't. Only cycling once
        print(str(numb))
        for tree in cursor:
            print('hi'+" "+str(count)+' '+str(tree[0]))
            count+=1
    del cursor
test=['OID@']
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sickTrees,test) as cursor:#tried for loop, was dumb
    for numb in distList:
        percentAvgCount=0.0
        for tree in cursor:#tried buffer, was dumb
            #select by oid tree[0] could select by attribute
            arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(sickTrees,'NEW_SELECTION','OBJECTID = '+str(tree[0]))
            arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(sickTrees, 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', sickTrees, numb, 'NEW_SELECTION', 'NOT_INVERT')#honestly, I'm just guessing how this actually works
            sickTreeCount=float(arcpy.management.GetCount(sickTrees).getOutput(0))
            #select by oid tree[0]
            arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(sickTrees,'NEW_SELECTION','OBJECTID = '+str(tree[0]))
            arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(healthyTrees, 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', sickTrees, numb, 'NEW_SELECTION', 'NOT_INVERT')
            helTreeCount=float(arcpy.management.GetCount(healthyTrees).getOutput(0))
            treePercent=sickTreeCount/(helTreeCount+sickTreeCount)
            percentAvgCount+=treePercent
    totalAvgPercent=percentAvgCount/float(numb)
    print(str(numb)+' %:'+' '+str(totalAvgPercent))
del cursor
```

Comment: No, that should not work. If you had a DA SearchCursor (`arcpy.da.SearchCursor`) it should work, but old-style (and effectively deprecated) cursors are not compatible with the `with` directive.

Comment: Thank you! At least that portion works now

Comment: Can you edit and update your question after you made the changes as commented? What is the error now? What is `sickTrees`,  `numb` and `distList`, can you show how you created them in your code snippet?

Comment: I've put the full code, in the question. What's left for me to do is have the cursor reset back to the first object, fix both SelectByLocation, and any other bugs that arise.
At this point the problems aren't related to the initial question

Comment: Your loop logic is flawed. Try using the cursor as a single pass, as documented.

Comment: I've updated the code!